# Passing arguments to jQuery .click WHILST keeping event parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, click, bind

I need to use bind the `click` event to an element in the DOM whilst being able to pass arguments on the fly, including the event object. My current script uses the following:

```
var counter = 1;
$(".dynamo_user_info .dynamo_awards").each(function(){
    $(this).find("~ div a").each(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("rel").split("aid-")[1];
        $(this).attr("id","dynamo_award-"+counter+"-"+id).bind('click',{c:counter,i:id},function(e){
            e.returnValue = e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault() ? false : false;
            dynamo.awards.tooltip.ini(c,i);
        });
    });
    counter++;
});
```

Now, as you can see, `counter` increases on each iteration and `id` does not hold a static value. After each iteration, the final values are: `counter = 4`, `id = 2`. Now whenever one of these elements is clicked, it `preventDefaults` as appropriate, then runs `dynamo.awards.tooltip.ini(c,i);`.

However, this does not work as intended. Instead of it running:

`dynamo.awards.tooltip.ini(1,1);`
`dynamo.awards.tooltip.ini(2,6);`

etc (for example), it instead runs:

`dynamo.awards.tooltip.ini(4,2);`
`dynamo.awards.tooltip.ini(4,2);`

i.e it uses the last stored values for `counter` and `id`. My guess is it does this due to how `bind` works, passing the parameters **when** the element is clicked, not before. I'm not sure how to fix this, unless I can trick the scope of the function in some way?

Comment: *Whilst!* Ahh, the English. `:)`

Comment: You need to understand [closure scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work). (See also [Bonsai!](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.closures) and boring old [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures))

Comment: just as a side note, this line seems redundant: `e.returnValue = e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault() ? false : false;`

Comment: I've been reading up on closure for a good few hours today but not understanding it well enough to abuse it.

Comment: You can just use `e.preventDefault()`. jQuery passes you a jQuery event, not the browser event. jQuery events always have `e.preventDefault()` and will in fact do this plumbing behind the scenes.

Comment: @ahren e.preventDefault() failed in some version of IE during testing (though said testing took place a few years back on an older version of jQuery).

Comment: @KeirSimmons You probably didn't use jQuery events, jQuery has normalized `.preventDefault` since 1.0 6 years ago

Comment: @Esailija Fair point, I'll remove the redundancy.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Would you be able to give me a pointer on how to use closure in this case?

Comment: Add `var c = counter, i = id;` to the `$.find().each()` scope, above the `$.click()` scope. This will maintain it's value in scope, you don't have to *bugger* (`!`) with the other *cruft* (`!`). Only thing, I'd use more expressive syntax, say `var self_counter = counter, self_id = id;`.

Comment: Here's me [abusing closures](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/kS3FG/) and [more abuse](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/S4ftm/) and yet I [take no mercy](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/SCKxf/)

Comment: @JaredFarrish It works perfectly, but I still can't see why. I can't get past why, without the initial `var` declaration, the scope is somehow different. Can you tell me exactly what the line `var self_counter = counter, self_id = id;` does explicitly?

Comment: Your comment is a little mangled, but it keeps the variable's value in scope, which is important. People will bitch if I try to explain it plainly, so read those links I provided. Seriously, closures are one of the power tools in Javascript. They're *brilliant*.

Comment: See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DLz92/1/ For comments *and* the **Whoa!** factor. Closures at work. (As well as the [related question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240479/javascript-to-make-a-fast-running-image-slideshow/9242332#9242332).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments are accessible through the event.data object , like

```
dynamo.awards.tooltip.ini(e.data.c, e.data.i);
```

http://api.jquery.com/bind/#passing-event-data