# Preloading Images not working

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue with my script.

I'm trying to load all the images in an array then check they are all loaded before continuing. But it's not working I equally do not get any errors so I'm not sure what is wrong.

This is what I have:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
          window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
          window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
          function( callback,  element){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 200 / 100);
          };
})();

function img_loader(){

for(var i in Images){
        Images[i]['img_src'].onload = function() {
            countImages ++;
        }
    }
}

function img_load_checker(){

    if(countImages == Images.length){
        return true;
    } else {
        requestAnimFrame( img_load_checker );   // keep checking
    }
}


window.countImages = 0;
img_loader();
    if(img_load_checker()){
            //this never gets executed - reason is unknown
    //continue with rest of the script
    }
```

This is the structure for `console.log(Images);`

```
[1: Object, 2: Object]
1: Object
img_src: <img>
2: Object
img_src: <img>
```

Can any one see the mistake?

Comment: When you say "it's not working" what do you mean specifically?

Comment: Did you try debuggin your code? What did console say? What does JSLint say?

Comment: `//continue with rest of the script` This part of the script never executes.

Comment: Take a look [at my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9242332/451969).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You if statement is NEVER going to work like that.

That funciton call is not going to magicaly sit there and wait until an asynchronous call is going to return.

```
if(img_load_checker()){
        //this never gets executed - reason is unknown
//continue with rest of the script
}
```

Use a call back!

```
for(var i in Images){
        Images[i]['img_src'].onload = function() {
            countImages ++;
            if (countImages == Images.length) {
                callSomeMethod();  <-- Call back
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
function img_load_checker(){

    if(countImages == Images.length){
        callNextStep();
    } else {
        requestAnimFrame( img_load_checker );   // keep checking
    }
}
img_load_checker();
```

Comment: Does this mean i cannot just do `return true`?

Comment: Yes, the funciton is firing asynchronously. By the time it would return anything, that if statement was done executing a long time ago.

Comment: Ah i see - strangely though on load never occurs. I put an alert test inside the on load function - wondering if it doesn't work when stored as objects.

Comment: Or you are setting the onload way to late and it never fires because it already did.

Comment: Is there way to do `onload || is_already_loaded`?  To cater to either situation ?

Comment: Check out this thread, selected answer talks about checking the parameters after the DOM has loaded. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821516/browser-independent-way-to-detect-when-image-has-been-loaded

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a timer:

```
Images[i]['img_src'].onload = function() {
    if(countImages++ >= Images.length)
    {
         loadingHasFinishedNowDoWhateverYouWant();
    }

}
```