# My script is not generating random images. Can someone tell me what the cause may be?

Tags: javascript, random

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

var mediaArray = new Array (
"images/Lab13/toshiba.jpg",
"images/Lab13/dell.jpg",
"images/Lab13/acer.jpg"
);

var max = mediaArray.length;
var randomIndex=0;


function showMedia()
{
randomIndex   = Math.floor((Math.random()*max));
document.getElementById("mediaimage").src= mediaArray[randomIndex];
setTimeout("showMedia()",1500);

}
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="ShowMedia();">
<div><a href="Javascript:mediaClick(randomIndex);">
<img src="images/Lab13/toshiba.jpg" id="mediaimage" /></a>
</div>
</body>
```

i think the function is not working correctly when i load the page it loads the 1st image "toshiba.jpg" but it does not change the image like it's supposed to

Comment: There's a litany of poor, outdated technique going on here. Did you find this script somewhere?

Comment: The function is called `showMedia()` but you're calling `ShowMedia()`. Please use the JavaScript error console for debugging.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dZJck/1/

Comment: @Albert - if you use firefox with firebug or chrome's built-in inspector, you can examine the console to find this type of problems (in firebug console: "ReferenceError: showMedia is not defined")

Comment: THANK YOU VERRY MUCH everyone its working!!!

Comment: @Jared Farrish yes it was in my Javascript school book -_-"

Comment: What? How old is it? Get rid of it, or don't try to learn it too much. Compare that to (not random but rapid slideshow) formatting I feature here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9242332/451969

Comment: @Jared Farrish its brand new My teacher wrote it and its full of mistakes like that i suppose
you all are going to see alot more of these questions from me here hahaha

Comment: Compare that to (not random but rapid slideshow) formatting I feature here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9242332/451969 It's heavily commented, but [without comments](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/DLz92/14/), it's got some different things going on. Modern things. *Better* things, like `[]` instead of `new Array()`, avoiding `body onload` inline handlers as well as `Javascript:`. And the most despised, `setTimeout('func()', ###);`

Comment: Well, it looks like what we did circa 2004. We didn't really know what we were doing in 2004. Mostly, that period was a mess. My condolences.

Comment: @Jared Farrish i can point to numerous scripts that are 10000 times better than the ones in my book but the thing is i have to do it the way its written there or i wont pass :( 
thank you for sharing

Comment: There's some really ridiculously cool stuff out there nowadays, like [d3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) ([yeah](http://dciarletta.github.com/d3-floorplan/)) and http://processingjs.com/. Beats *DHTML* to pieces. Don't get discouraged, pass and all. There's so much cool stuff out there now, though. Try http://eloquentjavascript.net/, http://codeacademy.org, and http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/ for updated information based on today's reality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no function `ShowMedia()`. JS is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `ShowMedia()` on page load:

```
<body onLoad="ShowMedia();">
```

which does not exist as javascript is case sensitive.

so correct code would be:

```
<body onLoad="showMedia();">
```