# javascript suppress error and continue in for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a speedtest by downloading 3 image files from the internet, and averaging the time it took to load them. If there is an error for whatever reason, I want to skip loading that image and proceed with the next one. If the error occurs on the last image, then I want to calculate the average speed at that point and return to the caller.

Right now, once an error occurs (I deliberately changed the url of an image so it doesn't exist), it won't go further. I've tried returning true from the .onerror function, but no luck. Any suggestions?

```
     var images = [{
            "url": 'http://<removed>250k.jpg?n=' + Math.random(),
            "size": 256000
        }, {
            "url": 'http://<removed>500k.jpg?n=' + Math.random(),
            "size": 512000
        }, {
            "url": '<removed>1000k.jpg?n=' + Math.random(),
            "size": 1024000
        }
    ];


function calculateBandwidth() {
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var startTime, endTime;
        var downloadSize = images[i].size;
        var download = new Image();
        download.onload = function () {
            endTime = (new Date()).getTime();

            var duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
            var bitsLoaded = downloadSize * 8;

            var speedBps = (bitsLoaded / duration).toFixed(2);
            var speedKbps = (speedBps / 1024).toFixed(2);
            var speedMbps = (speedKbps / 1024).toFixed(2);

            results.push(speedMbps);

            //Calculate the average speed
            if (results.length == 3) {
                var avg = (parseFloat(results[0]) + parseFloat(results[1]) + parseFloat(results[2])).toFixed(2);
                return avg;
            }
        }
        download.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log("Failed to load image!");
            return true;
        };
        startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        download.src = images[i].url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into try/catch blocks

Comment: you are returning when it fails thats why i guess

Comment: There is no need to return, once you return you are breaking your loop

Comment: I did something [similar here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240479/javascript-to-make-a-fast-running-image-slideshow/9242332#9242332) ([fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DLz92/1/), may be slow to load). I would think the reason you're not getting any satisfaction is that, if you're going to chain the requests, you have continue the process if `onerror` too. So it's not `return true/false;`, it's "ok error, handle it, now more images, or complete the test?" From the error handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're not doing is controlling the process as each event occurs. Each `onerror` and `onload` tells you that the process *stopped*, not that it should *quit* per se. You initialize one image, it doesn't load, maybe take note, otherwise continue.

The thing is, *you do the same thing at the end of `onload` too*. That is, do whatever measurements, then move to the next or, if no more, run the script that cleans up and reports or whatnot.

For instance:

```
var site = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/',
    imgs = [
    'wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Brandenburger_Tor_2004.jpg',
    'wikipedia/commons/a/ad/Cegonha_alsaciana.jpg',
    'wikipe/Cegonha_alsaciana.jpg',
    'wikipedia/commons/d/da/CrayonLogs.jpg',
    'wikipedia/commons/1/17/Bobbahn_ep.jpg',
    'wikipedia/commons/9/90/DS_Citro%C3%ABn.jpg',
    'wikipedia/commons/f/f0/DeutzFahr_Ladewagen_K_7.39.jpg',
    'wikipedia/commons/c/c7/DenglerSW-Peach-faced-Lovebird-20051026-1280x960.jpg',
    'wikipedia/commons/4/4d/FA-18F_Breaking_SoundBarrier.jpg'
];
```

My array of images. Hint, `wikipe/Cegonha_alsaciana.jpg` won't load. Be forewarned, these are large and load slowly and I use a cache buster to keep them firing `onload`s.

```
getimg();
```

In the fiddle, this is all within a `window.onload` event handler, so when that gets called, this initializes the process. I don't have a setup phase, per se, or otherwise I might have called it `init()` or `setup()`.

```
function getimg() {
    var img = document.createElement('img'),
        path = imgs.shift();

    if (path) {
        img.onload = loaded;
        img.onerror = notloaded;
        img.src = site + path + '?cach=bust' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999);

        console.log('Loading ', img.src);

        document.body.appendChild(img);
    } else {
        console.log('Finished loading images.');
    }

    function loaded(e) {
        console.log('Loaded ', e.target.src);
        next();
    }

    function notloaded(e) {
        console.log('Not loaded ', e.target.src);
        next();
    }

    function next() {
        console.log(imgs.length, ' imgs left to load.');
        getimg();
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/vfTfP/

This does what you're trying to do, without the timing mechanism built-in. I can break things off into steps, actions and events, so that I can control the steps as necessary. In a basic way, your script should not run much differently.