# How to create a series of animation in my case?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have series of images that I want to play them as a series of animation in html

```
<img src='image1.png' />
<img src='image2.png' />
<img src='image3.png' />
<img src='image4.png' />
<img src='image5.png' />
<img src='image6.png' />
<img src='image7.png' />
<img src='image8.png' />
<img src='image9.png' />
<img src='image10.png' />
<img src='image11.png' />
<img src='image12.png' />
```

They all need to on the same position but just swap very fast from `image 1` to `image 12` to make it looks like an animation.

Is there a way to do this properly? I have searched google but had no luck. Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DLz92/1/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240479/javascript-to-make-a-fast-running-image-slideshow so... you just need extremely fast slideshow, without effects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is only to have one Image and only change the image src attribute. Like

```
<img src="image1.png" id="animationImage" />
```

Afterwards you can simply change for example with an setInterval:

```
var imageId = 1;
window.setInterval("changeImage()", 100);
function changeImage(){
    imageId++;
    if (imageId > 12)
        imageId = 1;
    $("#animationImage").attr("src", "image" + imageId + ".png");
    // if you are NOT using jQuery, use this line instead:
    document.getElementById("animationImage").src = "image" + imageId + ".png"
}
```

of course you can also simply hide/add the images:

HTML

```
<img src="image1.png" class="animationImage" />
<img src="image2.png" class="animationImage" />
<img src="image3.png" class="animationImage" />
<img src="image4.png" class="animationImage" />
<img src="image5.png" class="animationImage" />
<img src="image6.png" class="animationImage" />
<img src="image7.png" class="animationImage" />
<img src="image8.png" class="animationImage" />
<img src="image9.png" class="animationImage" />
<img src="image10.png" class="animationImage" />
<img src="image11.png" class="animationImage" />
<img src="image12.png" class="animationImage" />
```

Javascript:

```
$(".animationImage:not(:first)").hide();
var imageId = 0;
window.setInterval("changeImage()", 100);
function changeImage(){
    $($(".animationImage")[imageId]).hide();
    imageId++;
    if (imageId > 11)
        imageId = 0;
    $($(".animationImage")[imageId]).show();
}
```

In both examples, the number `100` represents the amount of milliseconds the application will wait before showing the next image.

**Edit** The last solution assumes to use the jQuery library.

Comment: You are right. Sometimes jQuery becomes so common for me that I forgot the possibility that someone do not use it ;-) So my solution is jQuery only, I forgot to mention that and edited my post accordingly. Thanks for your hint. EDIT: I have edited my first solution so that it is usable also without jQuery

Comment: People don't use jQuery...? I don't understand. That's like going outside to tan, but laying in the shade instead.

Answer (score 1):

### Note: jQuery is required for this solution

---

I will do this using jQuery:

```
function swap()
{
    var images = $("img");
    var on = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
    {
        if($(images[i]).css("display") != "none")
        {
            on = true;
            $(images[i]).css("display", "none");
        }
        else if(on)
        {
            on = false;
            $(images[i]).css("display", "block");
        }
    }

    if(on)
    {
        $(images[i]).css("display", "block");
    }
}
```

This will swap each image to the next in order when called:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){swap();}, 1000/30);
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bHMYy/)