# Calling a function on mouse over

Tags: javascript, function, onmouseover, onmouseout

Ok, I should change the title. It works if the hover is over the entire page, but if I put the hover only over a div, it doesn't work.

inside the body:

```
<div id="gallery">
  <img src="slides/BarbedWire.jpg" alt="Barbed Wire" />
  <img src="slides/Feather.jpg" alt="Feather" />
</div>
```

inside the script. THIS WORKS:

```
function startSlider() {loop=setInterval ( moveRight, 1000 )}
startSlider();

function stopLoop(){
window.clearInterval(loop)}

onmouseover = stopLoop;
onmouseout = startSlider;
```

THIS DOESN'T WORK:

```
function startSlider() {loop=setInterval ( moveRight, 1000 )}
startSlider();

function stopLoop(){
window.clearInterval(loop)}

gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');
gallery.onmouseover = stopLoop;
gallery.onmouseout = startSlider;
```

Comment: `At the moment I'm not using jquery, only javascript.` what do you mean, I can see you are using jQuery?

Comment: am I? I thought that was only javascript, I'm confused about which is which. I tried with hover and it didn't wirk though.

Comment: in jQuery the event handler method is `mouseover` not `onmouseover`, you can also use 'hover'. However if you really aren't using jQuery, then that won't work anyway, you will want to try: `document.getElementById('gallery').onmouseover = function() {stopSlider();};`

Comment: @user3529946 Whenever you use `$()`.. that's very much jQuery my friend ;)

Comment: I want to stopLoop on mouse over and startSlider on mouse out

Comment: Make sure DOM is ready when you bind events.

Comment: @Akurn I've edited the post, it still doesn't stop. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @dfsq I'm not sure how can I check that? The thing just slides until it finishes, hovering doesn change anything. (I've edited the post). Thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5KEqr/

Comment: @JaredFarrish thanks for the demo. However the only way it works in my case is without the id. This works:
    function startSlider() {loop=setInterval ( moveRight, 1000 )}
    startSlider();
    
    function stopLoop(){
 window.clearInterval(loop)}

    onmouseover = stopLoop;
    onmouseout = startSlider;
I wonder WHY doesn't the id of the div work? I really need the hovering to be only on the div area, not the entire web page..

Comment: There's something that else you're doing then that you haven't provided; what I posted works exactly as it's given and you've specified. It's obvious by what you've edited into your question that you didn't copy and paste the code exactly as I provided it (replacing `function moveRight()`). The `window.onload` is there for a reason, as is the `var loop, gallery = ...` and the functions declared inside of it. It appears you're trying to cherry pick parts of it, without reconstructing the pieces that are needed in the form they are needed in.

Comment: To wit: Simply using `gallery = document.getElementBy...; gallery.onmouseover...` will not resolve your problem. Read the WHOLE script. If `#gallery` isn't working, then you're trying to attach the event handlers for it before it exists in the DOM. Hence, the `window.onload` wrapped around all of that code (and the local `var`s I've declared).

Comment: @JaredFarrish oh I see, but if I use the window.onload , does this mean all the pictures in the gallery will have to load (download) for the webpage to appear? IF so, that can be slow if the pictures are large.

Comment: You could use `$(document).ready()` instead of `window.onload`. If you're looking for a script that can show you how to wait, [see one of my other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9242332/451969).

Comment: @JaredFarrish ok, it works but not quite :). I've put the code from your example apart from defining moveRight function which  is defined earlier. If I remove the startSlider(); so everything is static on refresh, then I hover the mouse over the div, and when the mouse is out, the slide starts, and then it stops as expected when the mouse is on top. If I leave the startSlider(); in there then the slide starts from the begining but faster and a bit jerky (like it's running twice), and it doesn't stop when hovering either. I tried putting the code on JSFiddle but no luck, it's massive. Thanks