# Pre-loading a website title banner & adding it to Cache

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok, so its been a while since I've built a website, and I'm trying to blow out the cobwebs, so to speak.

I have built the following website: http://pinkgiraffecakes.tk/

As you may have noticed, it takes a long time to load the Title Bar. I am aware that you can pre-load images using Java and CSS, but the solutions provided all seem to be for use on other pages (i.e. pre load images on the home page so they are quicker to appear on other pages).

What I would like to do, is to pre-load the title bar and all the other associated images, store them to the cache, THEN show the homepage.

Is this possible? If so, could someone please provide sample code or a link to a tutorial on how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Create a `/loading.html` page, redirect to the page if it hasn't been visited by that "user" (store it in a session or cookie), do your preloading with whatever images, then redirect back to the page when completed. Or, hide the content area and show a loading `div` until the preloaded images are all loaded. I have a preload images answer, let me see if I can find it. Edit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9242332/451969

Comment: Java != Javascript... Anyway, your image is 3.4MB, which is ridiculous. Since you don't need any transparent elements, you can compress it a bit (and go to around 100-200KB) and forget about preloading.

Comment: @Shomz what would be the highest resolution/size you would recommend?

Comment: No, no, keep the resolution, keep everything... Let me do it for you, give me a sec.

Comment: Here is the 46KB version that would load in an instant. It's converted to 60% JPG: http://i.imgur.com/cWWoTGt.jpg Try playing with compression rates to get the best size/quality. Also, you might want to fix that bottom transparent part, like setting a pink background.

Comment: Thanks for going the extra mile!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, you should scale and optimize your images before resorting to lazyloading, preloading and shenanigan-loading. I [ran pingdom on your site](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/38ppB/http://pinkgiraffecakes.tk/) and almost choked.

- The main title weights 3.5MB, but it can be [optimized lossless to 185Kb](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3133731/website_title_banner.png)
- The facebook button weights 3.5MB too, and it can be [optimized lossless to 68Kb](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3133731/facebook_20pink5.png).

I just shaved over 7MB from your home screen.

Besides that, you're serving 1280x720px images as 150px x 75px buttons. You really need to display a scaled version instead of using the raw image with fixed height and width.